# spark-cassandra-connector - Creating Table from Dataframe - StructType?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm trying to write to Cassandra from a Spark dataframe. When I have a simple dataframe schema, as in the examples, it works:

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- url: string (nullable = true)
```

However, when I try to write a dataframe that includes StructTypes, with a schema like this:

```
root
 |-- crawl: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
```

Then I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported type: StructType(StructField(id,StringType,true))
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.types.ColumnType$.unsupportedType$1(ColumnType.scala:132)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.types.ColumnType$.fromSparkSqlType(ColumnType.scala:155)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.mapper.DataFrameColumnMapper$$anonfun$1.apply(DataFrameColumnMapper.scala:18)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.mapper.DataFrameColumnMapper$$anonfun$1.apply(DataFrameColumnMapper.scala:16)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.mapper.DataFrameColumnMapper.newTable(DataFrameColumnMapper.scala:16)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.TableDef$.fromDataFrame(Schema.scala:215)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.DataFrameFunctions.createCassandraTable(DataFrameFunctions.scala:26)
```

My code looks like this:

```
val df = sqlContext.read.parquet(input)
df.createCassandraTable(keyspace, table)

df.write
  .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
  .options(Map("table" -> table, "keyspace" -> keyspace))
  .save()
```

Help?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the connector does not currently support creating UDT types on the fly from DataFrame Structs. You should add a Ticket to the Spark Cassandra Connector Jira with that as a feature request. Until that is ready you can always manually create a new type to match your struct type.

Comment: I have the same problem, what do you mean "manually create a new type to match your struct", can you please elaborate more on this?

Comment: Meaning the nested struct defines a udt. You must define a UDT in c* and make a table with that udt in it manually.